# Disabling submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I have the following code:

```
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#yourSubmitId').click(function()
    {
        /*$(this).attr('disabled',true);*/
        $(this).prop('disabled',true);
        $(this).css({display:'none'});

        /* your submit stuff here */

        return false;
    });

    /*refreshing the page bringas back the submit button*/
    window.location.reload();
});
//--><!]]>
</script>

</head>
<body>

<h2>Test disabling submit button for 1 minute...</h2>

<br/>


<form id="yourFormId" name="yourFormId" method="post" action="#">
<input type="image" id="yourSubmitId" name="yourSubmitId" src="C:\images 
\submitButton_grey.jpg" alt="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Currently the submit button get disabled and hidden after it has been pressed.

How do I go about refreshing the page in order to bring back the submit button only after 1 minute after the submit button has been pressed..

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't really need to disable the button if it's going to be hidden anyway with `display:'none'`, and you don't need to refresh the page if you just un-hide the button instead. So you could just do this:

```
$(this).hide(1).delay(60000).show(1);
```

If you pass a duration to [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and `.show()` (even a short duration like 1ms) then the hide and show effects are added to the animation queue and you can therefore use the [`.delay()` method](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) in between them.

For more generic delayed execution use the [`setTimeout()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout).

Comment: easy and simple, not sure why I wanted to disable the button in the first place... Thanks.